# Scala - combine list of items into object

Tags: scala

Say I have the following:

```
trait PropType
case class PropTypeA(String value) extends PropType
case class PropTypeB(String value) extends PropType

case class Item(
    propTypeA: PropTypeA,
    propTypeB: PropTypeB
)
```

and that I'm given a `List[PropType]`. How would I go with combining this into a `List[Item]`?

That is (and assuming we only have `PropTypeA(name: String)` and `PropTypeB(name: String)` to make this shorter / easier to follow hopefully) given this:

```
List[PropType](
    PropTypeA("item1-propTypeA"),
    PropTypeB("item1-propTypeB"),
    PropTypeA("item2-propTypeA"),
    PropTypeB("item2-propTypeB")
]
```

I'd like to get the equivalent of:

```
List[Item](
    Item(PropTypeA("item1-propTypeA"), PropTypeB("item1-propTypeB")),
    Item(PropTypeA("item2-propTypeA"), PropTypeB("item2-propTypeB"))
)
```

Kind of table building from linearized rows across columns, if that makes sense.

Note that in general there might be incomplete "rows", e.g. this:

```
List[PropType](
    PropTypeA("item1-propTypeA"),
    PropTypeB("item1-propTypeB"),
    PropTypeB("itemPartialXXX-propTypeB"),
    PropTypeA("itemPartialYYY-propTypeA"),
    PropTypeA("item2-propTypeA"),
    PropTypeB("item2-propTypeB")
]
```

should generate the same output as the above, with the logic being that `PropTypeA` always marks the start of a new row and thus everything "unused" is discarded.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work with examples you mentioned.

```
    list.grouped(2).collect { case Seq(a: PropTypeA, b: PropTypeB) => Item(a,b) }.toList
```

However it is unclear from your question what other cases you want to handle and how. For example, how exactly do you define the "partial" occurrence. Are there always two elements in reverse order? Can there be just one, or three? Can there be two As in a row? Or three? Or two Bs?
For example, `A, A, A, A, B` or `B, B, A, A, B` or just `A`?

Depending on how you answer those question, you'll need to somehow "pre-filter" the list before hand.

Here is an implementation based on the last phrase in your question: "PropTypeA always marks the start of a new row and thus everything "unused" is discarded." It only looks for instances where an `A` is immediately followed by `B` and discards everything else:

```
    list.foldLeft(List.empty[PropType]) { 
      case ((a: PropTypeA) :: tail, b: PropTypeB) => b :: a :: tail  
      case ((b: PropTypeB) :: tail, a: PropTypeA) => a :: b :: tail 
      case (Nil, a: PropTypeA) => a :: Nil 
      case (_ :: tail, a: PropTypeA) => a :: tail 
      case (list, _) => list 
    }.reverse.grouped(2).collect { 
      case Seq(a: PropTypeA, b: PropTypeB) => Item(a,b)
    }.toList
```

If you have more than just two types, then there are even more questions: what happens if stuff after `A` comes in wrong order for example? Like what do you do with `A,B,C,A,C,B`?

But basically, it would be the same idea as above: if next element is of the type you expect in the the sequence, add it to the result, otherwise discard sequence and keep going.

Answer (score 1):

we can use the tail recursion function to generate the list of a new type.

```
def transformType(proptypes: List[PropType]): List[Item] =
{
  // tail recursion function defined
  @tailrec
 def transform(proptypes: List[PropType], items: List[Item]): List[Item]=
  {
    proptypes match {
      case (first:PropTypeA) :: (second:PropTypeB)  :: tail=> transform(tail, items :+ Item(first, second))
      
      case (first:PropTypeA) :: (second:PropTypeA)  :: tail => transform(second :: tail, items :+ Item(first, PropTypeB("")))
      
      case (first:PropTypeB) :: tail  => transform(tail, items :+ Item(PropTypeA(""), first))
      
      case (first:PropTypeA) :: tail  => transform(tail, items :+ Item(first, PropTypeB("")))
    
      case _ => items
      
    }

  }
  transform(proptypes, List.empty[Item])
}
```

[you can find the working link here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/vimitdhawan/g5UupkF0QLSNoETZ92TwYg/9)

Comment: Do not append things to `List`, that makes your implementation quadratic. Also, loose he curly braces around `case` bodies, they look ugly.

Comment: You can write things like `case first :: tail if (first.isInstanceOf[PropypeA])` as `case first: ProptypeA :: tail => `